# How do I fix warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wanted to ask how to get rid of warning that says assignment from incompatible pointer type.
This is the code I use:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a2d[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    int **pa;
    pa=a2d;
}
```

And getting this:

```
7:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type pa=a2d;
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: in all fairness, 1d arrays and pointers are inter-operable. but this is no more true for 2 and more dimensions arrays

Comment: A pointer of type `int**` has to point to an object of type `int*`. There is no object of type `int*` in your program. `a2d` is an object of type `int[2][2]`, consisting of two objects of type `int[2]`, each of which consists of two objects of type `int`. You can derive pointer *values* from each of these, but there are no `int*` pointer objects unless you define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking to decay your 2d array to array of pointers to array elements. In this case:

```
int a2d[2][2] = { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } };
int (*pa)[2] = a2d;
```

To access 4:

```
printf("%d\n", pa[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When this

```
 pa=a2d;
```

executes, compiler shoots the warning/error(depends upon whether you are using `-Werror` or not) as

```
main.cpp:7:8: error: cannot convert 'int [2][2]' to 'int**' in assignment

    7 |     pa=a2d;

      |        ^~~

      |        |

      |        int [2][2]
```

and this error is valid as `a2d` is two dimensional array, that doesn't mean its of `int**` type, similar to the concept of ***array is not pointer***.

To make things works `pa` should be ***pointer to an array*** not double pointer `int**`. For example

```
int a2d[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int (*pa)[2] = a2d; /* pa is pointer to an array */
```

here `pa` can point to `2` elements at a time i.e `pa` points to `a2d[0]` base address and `pa+1` will points to `a2d[1]` base address.

Comment: This “fix” might get the code to compile, but it won’t make it work. The types are not compatible, and telling the compiler to pretend that they are doesn’t make it so.

Comment: yes @PeteBecker you are right. just to remove warning I  suggested explicit type conversion.

Comment: The goal is not to remove the warning. It’s to write code that works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is wrong, you can't parse 2d array to pointer to pointer.
Your code should like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a2d[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    int * pa;
    pa=&a2d[0][0];
}
```

Becasue 2d array isn't double pointer. But this works:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ad[2]={4,5};
    int * pa;
    pa=ad;
}
```

But it's passing its address. But if you write:

```
    int a2d[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    int ** pa;
    pa=a2d;
```

It passing address of a2d array to double pointer...